# unable to filter the Date field in ngTable of angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

I am working on angularjs ngTable.I am facing issue with the filter of the date field in the table..

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/LftGsnapD6QiZDewqz1P?p=preview

In the table filter, when typed 2018 no results are shown in the table. I tried to filter date field as text `filter="{ orderDate: 'text'}"` but didn't worked.

sample:

```
  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
   <tbody ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <tr> 
    <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
    {{user.name}}</td>
    <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
    {{user.age}}  </td>
    <td title="'Order Date'" filter="{ orderDate: 'text'}" sortable="'orderDate'">
    {{user.orderDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}} </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the model your orderDate is an epoch (orderDate:1521836610848....). It should be a date or a string in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".